# Gerrit Reviewers name and email in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, email-ext

I am trying to integrate Gerrit Code Review with Jenkins and I need to get an email names of all Reviewers that are assigned to a change that triggered Jenkins job.
I have found [this](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gerrit-code-review/) fragment of Gerrit Code Review plugin with all environmental variables listed, but there is nothing about reviewers.

My goal: send email notification about job status (in Jenkins job Post-Actions via email-ext plugin) to change owner, reviewers patchset creators and job owner.

My question is: is there any way of obtaining Gerrit Reviewers emails and parsing them into Jenkins as a variable?

Comment: Take a look at your Gerrit document. Gerrit provides ssh cli and rest apis to retrieve the details of a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API, like in the following example:

```
curl --silent --user USER:PASS --request GET  https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/reviewers | sed 1d | jq --raw-output '.[].email'
```

See more info on Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html).

Comment: Thank you! That solves everything. For clarification: to get not username but email, just change .[].username to .[].email

Comment: I changed "username" to "email" in the answer. Thanks.